# Reading from Kafka with pyflink not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, pyflink

This is `apache flink` example with `pyflink`. [Link](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/python/examples/datastream/connectors.html#kafka-with-csv-format)

I want to read records from the `kafka` topic and print them with `pyflink`. When I want to produce to `kafka` topic it works, but I can't read from that topic.

Error when consuming from kafka topic:

```
raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o0.execute.
: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create stage bundle factory! INFO:root:Initializing Python harness
```

My `kafka` cluster is running.

I checked out that with `pyflink-1.17.0` and `pyflink-1.15.4`.

Comment: Did you get solution? Even i am facing same issue.

Comment: @user3024119 What is your operating system? I used Windows and it's not worked. But it worked in Linux.

Comment: You can check out the answer on my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76959190/unable-to-consume-data-using-the-latest-pyflink-kafka-connector) here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working code, update the schema according to your needs:

```
import logging
import sys

from pyflink.common.time import Instant

from pyflink.common import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.table import (DataTypes, TableDescriptor, Schema, StreamTableEnvironment)
from pyflink.table.expressions import lit, col
from pyflink.table.window import Tumble
from pyflink.common.time import Instant
from pyflink.table import StreamTableEnvironment, EnvironmentSettings, Schema
from pyflink.table import (DataTypes, TableDescriptor, Schema, StreamTableEnvironment)
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import FlinkKafkaProducer, FlinkKafkaConsumer
from pyflink.datastream.formats.json import JsonRowSerializationSchema, JsonRowDeserializationSchema

env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
execution_config = env.get_config()
    
settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance()\
                      .in_streaming_mode()\
                      .build()
    
env.add_jars("file:///home/path-to-kafka-connector/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.0.jar")
env.set_parallelism(2)
    # create table environment
tbl_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment=env,
                                            environment_settings=settings)
deserialization_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.Builder() \
            .type_info(Types.ROW_NAMED(\
                [   "id",
                    "name",
                    "high_price",
                    "low_price"
                    ], \
                [Types.INT(), Types.STRING(), Types.DOUBLE(), Types.DOUBLE()
                ])) \
                .build()

kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
topics='topic_name',
deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
properties={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': 'group_name'}
)

kafka_consumer.set_start_from_earliest()
ds = env.add_source(kafka_consumer)
ds = ds.map(update_openTime).print()
env.execute()
```