# Unable to consume data using the latest Pyflink Kafka connector

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, pyflink

I am trying to read the data from the `Kafka topic`. Kafka is set up fine. Now, when I wrote the code using `PyFlink` and no matter if I add the jars or not, the error remains the same.

```
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import KafkaSource, KafkaOffsetsInitializer
from pyflink.datastream.stream_execution_environment import StreamExecutionEnvironment, RuntimeExecutionMode
from pyflink.common import SimpleStringSchema, Configuration


class SourceData(object):
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.env.set_runtime_mode(RuntimeExecutionMode.STREAMING)
        self.env.set_parallelism(1)
        self.config = Configuration()
        self.config.set_string("pipeline.jars", "file:///../jars/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.1.jar")
        self.env.configure(self.config)


    def get_data(self):
        source = KafkaSource.builder() \
            .set_bootstrap_servers("localhost:9092") \
            .set_topics("test-topic") \
            .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest()) \
            .set_value_only_deserializer(SimpleStringSchema()) \
            .build()
        self.env \
            .add_source(source) \
            .print()
        self.env.execute("source")


SourceData(StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()).get_data()
```

**Environment**:

1. Flink 1.17.1
2. Java 11
3. Kafka Client latest one
4. Python 3.10.11

Error:

```
TypeError: Could not found the Java class 'org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource.builder'. The Java dependencies could be specified via command line argument '--jarfile' or the config option 'pipeline.jars'
```

I also tried without `config` option and using `env.add_jars` but, still the error remains the same. Do I need to configure anything else?

The **Second** option I tried was copying the `jar` to the `pyflink>lib` inside the `site-packages` of my virtual environment. After doing this, I am getting the below error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o12.addSource. Trace:
org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Py4JException: Method addSource([class org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource, class java.lang.String, null]) does not exist
```

Comment: What happens when you instead try to use `the config option 'pipeline.jars'`? You shouldn't go manually copying files around. That's the purpose of the `--jarfile` CLI option

Comment: @OneCricketeer As far as I saw on the documentation, the `config` option is for table API, and `add_jars` is for datastream. The error remains the same(as mentioned in the first option) even if I use the `add_jars` or `config` option.

Comment: Which version of the JAR did you add?

Comment: The latest 1.17.1 since I am using the latest Flink version which is linked in the documentation. I downloaded it from there.

Comment: Okay, just checking since `Method ... does not exist` usually means there is an API version mismatch

Comment: Yeah thanks, I definitely know there is some mismatch in the version but unable to figure it out.

Comment: @OneCricketeer for me putting the jars inside `pyflink -> lib` is working fine . however, when I try to use the below line instead of copying the jars, it doesn't work `self.env.add_jars("file:///kafka-clients-3.4.0.jar", "file:///flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.1.jar")` Any hints?

Comment: Also, it seems that `KafkaSource` is a bit buggy because no matter whatever solution you try, it doesn't work. However, `FlinkKafkaConsumer` works fine even though it is deprecated.

Comment: Does the user running the Flink process have read access to those JARs or the directory they're stored in? Have you tried using an absolute filesystem path? Is there a way you can print the environment config after adding the jars to ensure it's being setup?

Comment: @OneCricketeer There is no problem w.r.t read access. However, I will try printing environment config.

Comment: Regarding the first error, it is a JAR-related problem, and it seems that the comments (and the answer below) could solve the issue.
For the second error, as far as I understood, the new Data Source API cannot be used with the `add_source`  (Java `addSource`) StreamExecutionEnvironment method, because it requires a `SourceFunction` as an argument, whereas the new Data Source API builds a `Source` instead. So you must use `from_source()`. However, I'm not sure  if `from_source` may be used to append multiple sources to the same datastream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below snippet:

```
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import KafkaSource, KafkaOffsetsInitializer
from pyflink.datastream.stream_execution_environment import StreamExecutionEnvironment, RuntimeExecutionMode
from pyflink.common import SimpleStringSchema, WatermarkStrategy


class SourceData(object):
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.env.add_jars("file:///Users/.../Downloads/flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.1.jar")
        self.env.set_runtime_mode(RuntimeExecutionMode.STREAMING)
        self.env.set_parallelism(1)

    def get_data(self):
        source = KafkaSource.builder() \
            .set_bootstrap_servers("localhost:9092") \
            .set_topics("test-topic1") \
            .set_group_id("my-group") \
            .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest()) \
            .set_value_only_deserializer(SimpleStringSchema()) \
            .build()
        self.env.from_source(source, WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks(), "Kafka Source").print()
        self.env.execute("source")
```

Probably the issue you were facing was w.r.t paths of the jar. Also, after reading your comments, I can say that you just need one jar as mentioned in the documentation. You don't need a `kafka-clients` jar as of now.

I am late to the party but may be it will help someone someday!